# Change days to hours with date_diff

Tags: php, datetime

```
$time = Whatever i want
$future_date = new DateTime(date('r',strtotime($time)));
$time_now = time();
$now = new DateTime(date('r', $time_now));
interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I');
```

When i run this... i get an output WITH days, you just cant see them. How can i roll the days into the hours (like to have 35 hours for example)?

This is part of a longer script im writing, im aware there are different ways of doing this....

EDIT

Using the answers below, i've come up with this:

```
$time = '2013-10-8 11:10:00';
$future_date = new DateTime($time);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);
$text = $interval->days * 24 + $interval->h . ':' . $interval->i;
```

I'm trying to output the hours and minutes in this format (00:00), WITH leading zeros. Now out of my depth...

Comment: No need to convert timestamp to `r` format via `date` and `strtotime` functions, `DateTime` can accept timestamp like `new DateTime('@timestampInteger')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example how to get difference between dates/timestamps in hours:

```
$future = new DateTime('@1383609600');
$now = new DateTime;
$diff = $now->diff($future);
echo $diff->days * 24 + $diff->h;
```

**Update:** if you wish to format output numbers with leading zeros, you can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function. Example of `sprintf()` use:

```
echo sprintf('%02d:%02d', $diff->days * 24 + $diff->h, $diff->i);
```

Comment: Updated my question based on this answer, can you help?

Comment: Edited my answer. p.s. for the future, if you have new questions you should post new questions, not edit old ones.